# Passing variables,arrays and objects to view with compact

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method in laravel that aims to pass data to views. I have data in variables, arrays and objects.

This is the method

```
public function view($id){
    $id = request()->segment(2);
    $items = Role::all(['name', 'display_name']);
    return view('text.ServicesEditUser',compact('items',$items));
    }
```

I also have this code

```
  $uid = Auth::id();
  $settings = Settings::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
  return view('text.settings',compact('settings'));
```

that i want to incorporate to the code above. Once i pass the settings to the view, i can access data like `$settings->language` for instance. I also want to pass a variable which is

```
$title = 'degrees of tilt';
```

to the first code snippet's compact method.

This is the method now with all the data i want to pass to the view

```
public function view($id){
    $id = request()->segment(2);
    $title = 'Tilt in degrees';
    $settings = Settings::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
    $users = User::where('id','=',$id)->get();
    $items = Role::all(['name', 'display_name']);
    return view('text.ServicesEditUser',compact('items',$items));
    }
```

How do i pass `$settings` ,`$title`,`$users` , `$items` to the view and how do i access each in view?

Answer (score 0):

`compact()` doesn't need dollar at start.

You can just add your code to view by:

```
$title = 'My title';
$settings = ['my', 'settings',];

return view('text.settings', compact('title', 'settings'));
```

Anyway you can pass your variables by array:

```
$settings = ['my', 'settings',];

return view('text.settings', [
    'title' => 'Title',
    'settings' => $settings,
]);
```

The last option is `with()` method:

```
return view('text.settings')
    ->with('settings', $settings)
    ->with('title', 'My title');
```

Get access to variables in the view by `{{ $title }}` and

```
@foreach ($settings as $sett)
    {{ $sett }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

When returning a view you can pass multiple variables like this.

```
return view('text.ServicesEditUser')
    ->with(compact('items',$items))
    ->with('variable2', $variable2);
```

See here the documentation about this - [Laravel Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views).

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
$variable = "Var";
$array = ["first" => "a", "second" => "b"];
$object = (object) $array;
return view('view',compact(['variable', 'array', 'object']));
```

In view:

```
{{$variable}}
{{$array['first']}}
{{$object->first}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did also work

```
public function view($id){
    $id = request()->segment(2);
    $title = 'Degrees of tilt';
    $settings = Settings::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
    $users = User::where('id','=',$id)->get();
    $items = Role::all(['name', 'display_name']);
    return view('text.ServicesEditUser', compact('title', 'settings','users','items'));
    }
```

in the blade view

```
<p>{{$title}}</p>
{{$settings->language}}
@foreach($items as $item)
<option value="{{$item->name}}">{{$item->display_name}}</option>
@endforeach

@foreach($users as $user)
<option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->email}}</option>
@endforeach
```

In settings

```
@if($settings)
$settings->language
@endif
```